# Main Menu Buttons change colour but dont understand how

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a main menu with buttons (days of the week). If data is stored in the database in reference to these days of the week then they will turn 'green'. I understand the SQL query itself but don't understand how colourChange function identifies each button and 'knows' how to change it. Can someone maybe explain how this works?

MainMenu.java

```
    private void colourChange() {
    Cursor result = myDb.checkColour();

    if (result.getCount() == 0) {                                                                   // If the result equals to 0 then do nothing.
        // Default colour remains

    } else {
                                                                                                    // if the result is not 0 then...
        while (result.moveToNext()) {                                                               // Move through each result...
            String day = result.getString(0);                                                       // and store the day (column 0) of the result in day
            findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(day + "button", "id", getPackageName()))      // Find the view by ID using getResources.getIdentifier and passing the following parameter (day)
                    .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSuccess));             // The variable colourSuccess stored in the colours.xml file sets the background colour green.
        }
    }
}
```

Database.java

```
    public Cursor checkColour() {                                                                      // a SELECT statement is used to SELECT DayOfWeek FROM RoutineTable and GROUP BY DayOfWeek and store this as result.

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT DayOfWeek FROM " + RoutineTable + " GROUP BY DayOfWeek", null);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through it with a debugger and inspect the variables?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break the code down.

> ```
> getResources().getIdentifier(day + "button", "id", getPackageName())
> ```

The `Resources.getIdentifier()` method allows you to access the various constants inside `R.java` dynamically, by name. `day + "button"` is the name of the resource and `"id"` is the type of the resource. So this method will return `R.id.[day]button`. If `day` holds `"sunday"`, then you're going to get `R.id.sundaybutton`.

> ```
> findViewById( [code from above] )
> ```

Now that `getIdentifier()` has returned a "real" id to you (like `R.id.sundaybutton`), `findViewById()` will search your layout for a `View` object with that `android:id` attribute. So if your layout includes a `View` with `android:id="@+id/sundaybutton"`, `findViewById(R.id.sundaybutton)` will return it.

> ```
> getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSuccess)
> ```

`Resources.getColor()` takes a color identifier (here `R.id.colorSuccess`) and returns the color value (perhaps it is green, maybe `0xFF00FF00`).

> ```
> setBackgroundColor( [color from above] )
> ```

This one is easy: it sets the background color of the specified `View`.

Altogether, you're going to iterate over the days of the week and

- build an identifier from the day of the week
- find a view using that identifier
- get a color value from your resources
- apply that color value to the found view's background

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent answer. 10/10 for quality and detail. Thank you so much for helping me out!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

Without seeing all of the code for the resource file information for the application it will be hard to give you a definite answer. Looking at the code it looks like it matches a resource with the day of the week returned in the query plus the word "button" in the current application. Then it sets the background color by looking in the color resource folder for a resource called "colorSuccess", which changes it to the color green.

Answer (score 0):

That `colourChange()` function firstly requesting to database return as cursor.
`while (result.moveToNext())` is looping while all rows of result.

```
getResources().getIdentifier(day + "button", "id", getPackageName())
```

That find resources by specified layout id.Example `"@+id/fridaybutton"`

Accoriding android api documents. function paramters is here.

```
getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```